# how to sum this field by date of each in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying QUERY sum field fines based on the dates of each I've tried with case and when but failed is there a solution?

my table

```
NIP     NAMA                  TANGGAL     JENIS_KEHADIRAN     DENDA
10016   Novi Irawati          2020-01-03    sakit             37500
10016   Novi Irawati          2019-12-19    ijin              50000
10016   Novi Irawati          2019-12-19    ijin              50000
10010   Muhammad Hayyi         2019-12-15   hadir             0
10011   Rifyal Ainul Yaqin    2019-12-16    hadir   0
10012   Misbahul Munir        2019-12-20    hadir   0
10013   Ari Arif Sholeh       2019-12-20    hadir   0
10014   Sopantoni Hendri C    2019-12-20    hadir   0
10015   Alfan                 2019-12-20    hadir   0
10017   Romiatul Jamil        2019-12-20    hadir   0
10018   Fidatul Hasanah       2019-12-20    hadir   0
10019   Abdul Muik            2019-12-20    hadir   0
```

My Query

```
select nip,nama,case
when month(tanggal) = month(tanggal) then sum(denda)
end as total_denda
from potongan_absen
group by nip
```

TABLE I WANT AFTER SUM

```
NIP     NAMA                  TANGGAL     JENIS_KEHADIRAN     DENDA
10016   Novi Irawati          2020-01-03    sakit             37500
10016   Novi Irawati          2019-12-19    ijin              100000
10010   Muhammad Hayyi         2019-12-15   hadir             0
10011   Rifyal Ainul Yaqin    2019-12-16    hadir   0
10012   Misbahul Munir        2019-12-20    hadir   0
10013   Ari Arif Sholeh       2019-12-20    hadir   0
10014   Sopantoni Hendri C    2019-12-20    hadir   0
10015   Alfan                 2019-12-20    hadir   0
10017   Romiatul Jamil        2019-12-20    hadir   0
10018   Fidatul Hasanah       2019-12-20    hadir   0
10019   Abdul Muik            2019-12-20    hadir   0
```

Comment: You appear to be summing denda by nip and tanggal?

Comment: i just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should produce the results you specify:

```
select nip, nama, min(tanggal) as tanggal,
       jenis_kehadiran, sum(denda)
from potongan_absen
group by nip, nama, jenis_kehadiran;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6e081d3c708302ee446d8362e71503b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: may i ask? why field tanggal using min()?

Comment: @AndrewLee . . . I may have misread the data.  That column can also be part of the `group by`.